# How Build Custom Forms in React

Tags: reactjs

We need to create custom Patient forms for our EHR app. These forms will vary by every office for which we have a customer. We use React, Spring and PostgreSQL as the database.

The process will be when we onboard a new office they will provide us a patient form which is customized for their office.

What is the best way of building this?

One of our developers proposed adding these custom Forms to S3 and then whenever a patient form is loaded the app will retrieve the patient form for that particular office and present it to the user.

Also, how is the best way to store the Patient data in PostgreSQL since each form will be customized and we'll need to be able to handle any new fields which need to be added for this particular form.

Seems very inefficient to have a Patient data table with 100s, perhaps 1000s of fields.

Answer (score 0):

There’s another way you can achieve this if that use case fits in your scenario. You can provide your user to create their own form by creating their own fields. For each field they can provide label or type of that field and options if type is checkbox or radio. In this way user can create their own forms and you can save those form templates in DB using JSON field. By JSON field you don’t have to take care about the DB columns for the form.